# Is there a tool for reporting downcasts in Java?

Tags: java, pmd

Wondering if there is a reporting tool (such as PMD) which reports downcasting in Java code.

Comment: findbugs: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#BC_IMPOSSIBLE_DOWNCAST

Comment: Alex, that rule finds just _impossible_ downcasts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catching all casts is easy with a custom PMD rule:

```
import net.sourceforge.pmd.AbstractJavaRule;
import net.sourceforge.pmd.ast.ASTCastExpression;

public class CastRule extends AbstractJavaRule {

    public CastRule() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object visit(final ASTCastExpression node, final Object data) {
        addViolation(data, node);
        return super.visit(node, data);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it catches upcasts too if they are explicit upcasts. Some example:

```
final Number myNumber = 5;
final Integer myInteger = (Integer) myNumber; // catched

final Number myNumber2 = (Number) myInteger; // catched
final Number myNumber3 = myInteger; // NOT catched
```

Catching only downcasts looks rather complicated with PMD.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467756/maven-plugin-to-restrict-specific-packages-from-being-used/7492441#7492441) too, it contains some details about the usage.

Comment: That's great - not a big deal that explicit upcasts are caught too. Sorry for the late reply.