# Forbid using certain packages in a Java project (especially unit tests)

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing

I'd like to prevent people from my team from using TestNG asserts and instead use AssertJ. I am aware of those solutions:
[Maven plugin to restrict specific packages from being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467756/maven-plugin-to-restrict-specific-packages-from-being-used)
Unfortunately, neither (restrict-plugin and macker) of them checks test directory. I'd like Maven to check both main and test source code.

Comment: I would suggest to look at [checkstyle rules](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_imports.html) in relationship with the [maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/)...