# Exclude lib needed in an external dependency

Tags: java, maven

I know there are a lot of questions answered for dependency exclusion with maven. Sadly I couldn't find an answer for my situation, since I don't want to replace the excluded lib with another version of my own.

Let me describe the exact problem.

We are using swagger for our REST endpoint documentation. Hence, swagger is declared a dependency in the pom file.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Swagger itself declares google guava as compile dependency like this:

```
springfox-swagger2
-> springfox-spi
   -> springfox-core
      -> guava
```

Now guava is available in our project and people start using it, which we want to prevent. I tried to exclude guava from the swagger dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
  <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Now Eclipse tells me that swagger is referencing a lib from guava that is not on the classpath. Isn't it possible to tell maven I don't want to have the transitive dependency in my project but let swagger use it as it may.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Maven dependency plugin with the analyze-only goal:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-only-mojo.html

Here, you can fail the build if someone directly uses a transitive dependency (without declaring it explicitly). This would especially fail the build if someone uses guava without putting guava into the pom.

Answer (score -2):

You could try static code analysis tools. Possible answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7475862/7550277

Or via Maven plugins: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15084217/7550277) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19808362/7550277).

Comment: We have one in use but that can't be it. Please, no.

Comment: We want to prevent it compile time. Not in an afterwards analysis. Maven must be capable of doing this somehow.

Comment: Then you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15084217/7550277) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19808362/7550277)